# Preventing syncing of Google+ contacts to Galaxy S3

Tags: contacts, sync, google-plus

Have done my bit of research but couldn't find a good solution. When I sync the contacts with my primary Gmail account, the Contacts get filled with all of my Google Contacts including those from Google+ (1000s of them) which I obviously do not want to be in my phone.

How do I prevent this from happening ?

1. I do not want to create a new Google account just as a workaround
2. Have tried to locate the possibility of syncing just with a specific group. But can't find it in S3
3. I do not prefer 3rd party contact managers

Answer (score 7):

Open the Google+ app. Click the MENU button and choose SETTINGS.

Uncheck ADD CONTACTS FROM GOOGLE+

Comment: This option was not on my Google+ App (Build 3.0.1.31545355) on my Droid 3 running Android 2.3.4

Comment: @DylanYaga It's only on ICS and newer. Before that you just hide the group that you don't want to see.

Comment: Is it possible that unchecking this will not remove the already synced contacts with? How can I remove those as well?

Comment: Ok it just took several minutes to make the change.

Answer (score 3):

`Settings > Accounts > Google > Google+ > UNCHECK "Keep Contacts up to date"`

Answer (score 2):

I didn't want all of my Google Contacts to display because that is not where I store phone #'s.  I was able to get the GS3 to only show contacts that have a phone # by going to:
Contacts > click on Settings button, scroll to bottom and click on Settings again and then choose "Only contacts with phones".  This way, I have my Google Contacts on there, but not the ones that I use only for emailing.

Answer (score 1):

An option I went with was that in my g-mail account, I deleted all my contacts. I then synced my s3 with my google account so that it updated with the 0 contact list. Once I cleared my contact list from my phone, I unchecked the syncing option so that I wouldn't have this problem again. Back on my gmail account, I undid deleting the contacts so that I could retain my contact list in my email (revert it back to before this process), but still have 0 of those contacts on my S3.

Hope that helps (even though it's 2 months late).

Comment: It sounds like this does only delete the Google contacts *and not* the Google+ contacts. Plus your device won't be able to sync the Google contacts in the future. Sorry, but I would not recommend this option.

Answer (score 0):

If [Sparx's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/26113/440) is not an option, the I suggest to simply hide the Google+ contacts  in the app. This does not prevent syncing but it's a sufficient  solution. For ICS open the contacts app, select the list view and press the context menu button, which should present a menu with the "Contacts to display" option.